Visual Studio database deploy deleting of triggers
We have a database project in Visual Studio, and we have defined an SQL trigger on a table.
Now, we don't need it anymore, but I can't remove it in a Visual Studio database publish.
I get "This deployment may encounter errors during execution because changes to [dbo].[TableName] are blocked by [dbo].[TriggerName]'s dependency in the target database."
The trigger is straight forward:
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerName]
    ON [dbo].[TableName]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
        Some UPDATEs here..
    END

Doing "DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS [dbo].[TriggerName]"
in PreDeployment-script gives the same error.
The DROP works fine in SSMS, so it looks like a bug in Visual Studio to me.
I read somewhere that someone changed the trigger to do nothing, but is that really what Microsoft wants us to do?
Thanks for any help I can get!

It could be due to dependencies between triggers and other database objects. If you remove the trigger directly from Visual Studio, you may get errors because of these dependencies.
It is recommended to check if the trigger has any dependent objects before trying to delete it. If dependencies are found, you may need to manually resolve them before trying to remove the trigger.
Additionally, you can try the following steps to remove triggers:

In Solution Explorer, find your database project.
Expand the project and find the "Triggers" folder.
In the Triggers folder, find the .sql file for the trigger you want to delete.
Right-click the file and select Delete.

In the publish configuration, make sure you’ve selected “Always re-create database” or “Drop objects in target but not in source”. This will ensure that the trigger is removed when published.

Thanks very much for your reply
I solved it in a strange way: first I changed the trigger to do nothing:
BEGIN
    noop:
END 

That went through the publishing.
Next was to remove the trigger altogether, which obviously had no dependencies. And that worked.
So I still think this is a bug in VS. If I could change the trigger to noop, dependency errors must have been false.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction about dependencies!
